# slicker way to do a mulitple str_replace

Tags: php, variables, str-replace

What is the best way to change multiple items using *str_replace*, rather than the following:

```
$dataMeta = str_replace(['fooboy_','foogirl_','foonut_'],['','',''],$source);
```

For example....

**Change:** fooboy_1234 | foogirl_5678 | foonut_0909

**To:** 1234 | 5678 | 0909

Comment: `str_replace(['fooboy_','foogirl_','foonut_'], "", $str);` ... you dont need to match the number of array if you aren't doing multiple different replacement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead

```
$string = 'foo_3456';
echo preg_replace('/[a-z]+_(\d+)/i', '${1}', $string);
```

live example [here](https://3v4l.org/bTcR4)

So using this simple approach, you will probably apply it to an array of strings, using for example [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function

```
$strings = ['foo_1234', 'bar_3456', 'foo_5678', 'bar_7890'];
$strings = array_map(
    function($string){
        return preg_replace('/[a-z]+_(\d+)/i', '${1}', $string);
    },
    $strings
);
var_dump($strings);
```

live example [here](https://3v4l.org/YHn6B)